# how can i train a model with 2 images stitched/overlap together?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have so far created 2 model which takes 2 different train datasets and compare the 2 datasets and give the resultant output by calling the model weights i get after training the models. Now i want to stitch/overlap the 2 images (say: image 1 of model1 train dataset and frame1 of image 1 of model2 train dataset).

What i mean is get the RGB channel from both the image, combine it and save it as single image. I can create 6 channels (RGB+RGB) but I don't know how can i combine them as one and save them.

Here is the code for calling 2 model weights and do the prediction.

```
model1 = create_model()
model1.load_weights('model1.h5')
print ('model1 loaded successfully')

model2 = create_model()
model2.load_weights('model2.h5')
print ('model2 loaded successfully')

import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
i = 1
while (i < 11):
   test_image1 = image.load_img('dataset/test_set/'+str(i)+'.jpg', 
   target_size = (64, 64))
   test_image2 = image.load_img('dataset2/test_set/'+str(i)+'.jpg', 
   target_size = (64, 64))
   test_image1 = image.img_to_array(test_image1)
   test_image2 = image.img_to_array(test_image2)
   test_image1 = np.expand_dims(test_image1, axis = 0)
   test_image2 = np.expand_dims(test_image2, axis = 0)

   result = model1.predict(test_image1)
   print ("result1=", result)
   result2 = model2.predict(test_image2)
   print ("result2=", result2)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply but i got what i actually wanted.using opencv

`img= cv2.addweighted(image1,0.7,image2,0.3,0)`

will join the two images one over another.

Comment: It above adds two images scaled with different weights called image blending: (0.7*image1 + 0.3*image2)+0.

Comment: yes and soon i figured out its keeping the channel as 3 but not 6. I want something 
 like this, that do this but also makes the channel as 6 from 3